# Changing the ActiveModel submitted by a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form that allows my admins to create users. I am using STI, so the admin can specify a type of `Admin` or `User`. If I submit the form with invalid information and the save fails, my controller re-renders the form using the `@user` model, like such:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name} user created"
    else
      render :new
  end
end
```

I am running into the problem that the submit button now submits a hash with information for `admin` instead of `user`, which means that my method for whitelisting params doesn't work:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :type, :role_id)
end
```

Is there a way that I can modify the submit button so that it submits as a `user` and not as an `admin`?

And the view with the button:

```
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
  = form_for [:admin, @user], html: {role: :form}, url: admin_users_path do |f|
    - if @user.errors.any?
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

    .row
      #first_name.form-group
        = f.label :first_name
        = f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'

    .row
      #last_name.form-group
        = f.label :last_name
        = f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control'

    .row
      #email.form-group
        = f.label :email
        = f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'

    .row
      .col-md-6
        #user_type.form_group
          = f.label :type
          = f.select :type, options_for_select(%w{Customer Admin}, selected: @user.type), class: 'form-control'

      .col-md-6
        #admin_role.form-group
          = f.label :role
          = f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name

    .row
      #password.form-group
        = f.label :password
        = f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'

    .row
      #password_confirmation.form-group
        = f.label :password_confirmation
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control'

    #submit.actions.text-center
      = f.submit
```

Comment: Can you post the view where the button is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `as: :user` option in `form_for`. More details in Rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-23form_for+with+a+model+object).